# Difference between task and process

Tags: terminology, definitions

I'd like to know which is the difference between a task and a process in computer science. I'm studying a course on real-time systems and there are some definitions that I don't know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. Note that different definitions of the same term may be valid. Nobody seems to know what tag *definitions* is about, and I think this question is not about *learning computer science disciplines and CS education*, but *how specific notions have to be understood*: [tag:terminology].

Comment: Hi @greybeard have I put only the tag terminology?

Comment: (That would have been *my* choice. Because I'm not sure, I purposely did neither indicate I reviewed your question (so the attention of further reviewers of posts by new contributors be drawn to it), nor suggest this as an edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference appears to be that "process" is a well-defined term with a specific meaning that is universally understood, whereas "task" is ambiguous and means different things to different people.

The following Stack Overflow questions on the same topic support this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042717/what-is-the-difference-between-a-thread-process-task
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560939/task-vs-process-is-there-really-any-difference

Microsoft Windows certainly conflates the two terms—the *Task Manager* is used to administer processes.

Comment: Hello @AaronRotenberg, thank you very much for your explanation.